# In Joomla 1.6, how to make a weblink to a local file (or an equivalent)?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.6

Is there any way I could make my web links to point to local files (relative paths)?

Once a month I upload a new file to the server and than I would like to add a new "web link" of an specified category (or what else...) to this file. Than, I have a WebLinks module listing the last 5 added files in the main page.

The is that WebLinks doesn't allow me to set a url as a relative path and use absolute path is not possible.

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

There are several extensions meant for handling files. Depending on what you are trying to do, any ones of these may work for what you need -

Phoca download - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads/5551

jDownloads - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads/2849

Docman - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads/10958

Remository - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads/83

Comment: just Phoca download currently supports Joomla 1.6. I'll give a try and come back soon to edit this comment.

Comment: no lucky. I couldn't find in Phoca Download a way to show just the last five files added to a category (as in Last News module). Any other suggestions?

Comment: Oh, you are on 1.6. You might have a problem finding an extensions as many devs are still working on porting their code to 1.6. You might try the Phoca Download module - http://www.phoca.cz/documents/20-phoca-download-section-menu-module/72-features. I have never used it, but it would be a good place to start if it doesn't do exactly what you need.